# Select model field with dynamic variable in controller C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

This might be a dumb question but I'm stuck on this one. I have an AJAX request that updates a field in my DB table. The AJAX request sends the following properties with it: int? id *(row id)*, string input *(new field value)*, string field *(which field should be updated)*

My controller code is as follows:

```
company c = db.companies.Find(id);
switch (field)
{
   case "telephoneNo":
       c.telephoneNo = Convert.ToInt32(input);
       break;
   case "rCode":
       c.rCode = Convert.ToInt32(input);
       break;
   case "pCode":
       c.pCode= Convert.ToInt32(input);
       break;
   default:
       c.field = input;
       break;
 }
```

I would like to dynamically select the DB field based on the Field property supplied by the AJAX request: **c.field** *(field is the dynamic variable)*, but at the moment I have to hardcode the field name, eg. **c.telephoneNo**, as it keeps complaining that there is no such db property named "field". How can I go about getting this to work?

Comment: what happens when the supplied field name is not in your model?

Comment: @GaganDeep, I have it in a try block which handles the exeptions

Comment: try the answer i have given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method,

```
company c = db.companies.Find(id);

try
{
   c.GetType().GetProperty(field).SetValue(c, input, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}


.....

//Update model
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use reflection to set the field by field name, as other answers suggest. However, the question is whether you *should* do that. As I understand, the value of the property `field` in your JSON object comes from the client. If you now start to use the value of that property for reflection, you give the client (and therefore a potential attacker) access to *any* property of your target object. That can cause security issues, so you will probably have to sanitize your input. When you sanitize it anyway, you can just as well go with your initial solution.

If you don't want to spell out the property names, you can use `nameof(Company.telephoneNo)` instead of `"telephoneNo"`. But even that is something you should carefully consider as you bar yourself of changing the internal property name (e.g. during refactoring) without affecting your external interface.

So I would say that your current solution is probably fine.

Comment: He could still use the reflection to set the values instead of that ugly case, and use array of accepted filed names to check/sanitize the input (if that is even issue in his cases)

Comment: @Dusan I don't find that `switch` particularily ugly. With one line (plus `break`) in each `case` it is reasonably easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use C# Reflection.

```
yourmodelobject
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty(propertyName)
        .SetValue(yourmodelobject, inputvalue, null);
```